# Concept to check for a nested class template

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Suppose I want to be able to write:

```
template<class T> concept WithNestedTemplate = ...;
struct F { template<class> using nested = int; };
static_assert(WithNestedTemplate<F>);
static_assert(!WithNestedTemplate<int>);
```

That is, `WithNestedTemplate` should check for the existence of `T::template nested` a member class template or alias template with signature `template<class> class`.

I can write a helper concept:

```
template<template<class> class> concept TemplateOfᐸclassᐳ = true;
template<class T> concept WithNestedTemplate = TemplateOfᐸclassᐳ<T::template nested>;
```

But this gives false positives in gcc (the concept erroneously accepts `int`, e.g.), it's difficult to give the helper concept a sensible name, and now its definition is potentially some way away from where it is used.

Or I can write a generic lambda with *tparams*:

```
template<class T> concept WithNestedTemplate = requires {
    []<template<class> class>(){}.template operator()<T::template nested>(); };
```

But this currently doesn't work in clang (it doesn't like lambdas in unevaluated context), is abominably ugly, and possibly unclear to the reader.

Is there a better way to do this - preferably one that works across all major compilers?

I should probably mention that *instantiating* `T::template nested` as the test is not going to work, since it would be legitimate for it to be constrained.

Answer (score 3):

Make a templated struct taking a `template <class> class` and check that the struct can be instantiated:

```cpp
template <template <class> class> struct TakesTemplate {};
template<class T> concept WithNestedTemplate = requires {
    typename TakesTemplate<T::template nested>;
};
```

[Compiler Explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/W6GGfzPsj)

Comment: That has (some of) the same issues (naming, locality) as my first suggestion. Good to see that it works across all compilers though.

Answer (score 0):

> But this gives false positives in gcc

I think this is because [temp.constr.normal#1.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.normal#1.4) IIUC:

> The normal form of a concept-id `C<A1, A2, ..., An>` is the normal form of the constraint-expression of `C`, after substituting `A1, A2, ..., An` for `C`'s respective template parameters in the parameter mappings in each atomic constraint. **If any such substitution results in an invalid type or expression, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required.**

---

> But this currently doesn't work in clang (it doesn't like lambdas in unevaluated context)

You can just `return true` from the lambda and invoke it to form a constant expression:

```cpp
template<class T> concept WithNestedTemplate =
    []<template<class> class>(){
        return true;
    }
    .template operator()<T::template nested>();
```

This should be ok because it is an [atomic constraint](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.constr.atomic#3) IIUC

> To determine if an atomic constraint is satisfied, the parameter mapping and template arguments are first substituted into its expression. **If substitution results in an invalid type or expression, the constraint is not satisfied.**